# Error de syntax en c# para un delete where

Tags: mysql, c#

```cs
string sqlQueryString = "Delete from Personas where DNI = " + txtBuscarDNI.Text + "";
sqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQueryString, cn);
cn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Me dice lo siguiente

```
Incorrect syntax near '='.
```

No encuentro el error de sintaxis, o estoy haciendo mal el query y olvidándome de algo?

Comment: Agrega comillas simples: `string sqlQueryString = "Delete  from Personas where DNI = '"+txt.BuscarDNI.Text+"'";`

Answer (score 2):

El problema se debe principalmente a que estás concatenando el valor del DNI a tu consulta, debes estructurar tu código, y además revisa el connectionString, asegúrate que no tenga espacios. Revisa ejemplos de uso de la clase `SqlCommand`

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#examples

Agregando comillas al valor del DNI, pero te sugiero mejor realizar el siguiente cambio:

```
private void btnBuscarEliminar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

string dni = txtBuscarDNI.Text;
string myQuery = "DELETE FROM Personas WHERE DNI = @DNI";

using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Losgordos\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=OficinaCelest...."))
{
    cn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(myQuery, cn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DNI", dni);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Me gusta la respuesta, de todas maneras, si uno ve la imagen puede notar que el código que proporciona es un tanto incorrecto, en el código de visualiza: txt.BuscarDNI pero en la imagen es: txtBuscarDNI

Comment: GRacias FRanco ,ya corregi, es txtBuscarDNI